# how to change edit url with "Id" to edit url with "Slug" in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, slug

I have this is WordPress Post editing Url:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=ID&action=edit
```

and I want to change it to **Slug** Not the **ID** Like This:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=Slug&action=edit
```

I was trying to edit the post with this Url but is not working:

```
https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=MyPostSlug&action=edit
```

Comment: There is a similat question asked many years ago: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172549/using-slug-instead-of-id-in-admin-edit-post-url I am still not sure if that can be done somehow, but I will spend a bit of time right now on this to try and get a solution. It's a nice challenge I guess

Comment: it looks like the same but, this question is not about WordPress

Comment: `this question is not about WordPress`. wait ... what?

Comment: you're right I didn't see the URL perfectly, I will try the method 

Comment: I am extremely curious why you need this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the edit post link structure, you can use the [`get_edit_post_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_edit_post_link/) filter like so:

```
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'so_73914075_get_edit_post_link', 10, 3);
function so_73914075_get_edit_post_link($link, $post_id, $context) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) ) {
        return $link;
    }

    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

    if ( 'revision' === $post->post_type ) {
        $action = '';
    } elseif ( 'display' === $context ) {
        $action = '&amp;action=edit';
    } else {
        $action = '&action=edit';
    }

    if ( 'display' === $context ) {
        $post_type = '&amp;post-type=' . $post->post_type;
    } else {
        $post_type = '&post-type=' . $post->post_type;
    }

    $custom_edit_link = str_replace( '?post=%d', '?post-name=%s', $post_type_object->_edit_link );

    return admin_url( sprintf( $custom_edit_link . $action . $post_type, $post->post_name ) );
}
```

This will change the edit links for regular posts and pages to something like this:

`https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post-name=the-post-slug&action=edit&post-type=post`

> **WARNING:** make sure you limit this to only the post types you need to change the URL for. Making this change global will almost surely
> have unintended effects over other plugins

However, making the admin panel actually load the edit screen is not that easy.

Looking at the source code of the [wp-admin/post.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/post.php) file, you will see that there is no way to hook into the flow and populate the `$post_id` variable with the post id matching the slug you are sending through.

That means you have 2 options:

1. **RECOMMENDED** Update the edit link to whatever format you want and then create an admin redirect function that pulls the slug from the initial URL and redirects to the actual edit page with the `?post=%d` in it.
2. **NOT RECOMMENDED** Create a new admin edit page that will understand your URL structure and include the `wp-admin/post.php` after the code that pulls the `$post_id` based on the slug.

The 2nd method might come with lots of extra code you need to write to cover all the cases and all the instances a post reaches the `post.php` in the admin panel